# What is regular expression for multi string?

Tags: lex

I am learning to make a compiler and it's got some rules like single string:

```
char ch[] ="abcd";
```

and multi string:

```
printf("This is\
a multi\
string");
```

I wrote the regular expression

```
STRING \"([^\"\n]|\\{NEWLINE})*\"
```

It works fine with single line string but it doesn't work with multi line string where one line ends with a `'\'` character. 
What should I change?

Comment: Why do you use the definition `{NEWLINE}` (whose value you don't show) instead of the more readable `\n`? It makes your code harder to read and your question harder to answer, since it quite possibly has to do with an error in the unnecessary definition. Also, you don't need to escape the quote inside a character class (`[...]`).

Comment: Previously, in my code, I wrote the rule NEWLINE \n. So wherever I needed \n, I wrote NEWLINE and yes I don't need to escape the quote inside a character class.

Comment: How you write your code is, of course, your decision. But if you use a definition then you need to include it in your question; otherwise how can we know what the real definition is? Code in questions should be self-contained. If the definition is correct, then so is the regular expression and the problem might have to do with trailing whitespace in your input. Or something elsewhere in your rules, although that would be a bit odd. It is always better to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, I should have included that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common string pattern is

```
\"([^"\\\n]|\\(.|\n))*\"
```

This will match strings which include escaped double quotes (`\"`) and backslashes  (`\\`). It uses `\\(.|\n)` to allow any character after a backslash. Although some backslash sequences are longer than one character (`\x40`), none of them include non-alphanumerics after the first character.

It is possible that your input includes Windows line endings (CR-LF), in which case the backslash will not be directly followed by a newline; it will be followed by a carriage return. If you want to accept that input rather than throwing an error (which might be more appropriate), you need to do so explicitly:

```
\"([^"\\\n]|\\(.|\r?\n))*\"
```

But recognising a string and understanding what the string represents are two different things. Normally a compiler will need to turn the representation of a string into a byte sequence and that requires, for example, turning `\n` into the byte 10 and removing backslashed newlines altogether.

That task can easily be done in a (f)lex scanner using start conditions. (Or, of course, you can rescan the string using a different lexical scanner.)

Additionally, you need to think about error-handling. Once you ban strings with unescaped newlines (as C does), you open the door to the possibility of an unterminated string, where a newline is encountered before the closing quote. The same could happen at the end of the file if a string is not correctly​ closed.

If you have a single-character fallback rule, it will recognise the opening quote of an unterminated string. This is not desirable because it will then scan the contents of the string as program text leading to a cascade of errors. If you are not attempting error recovery it doesn't matter, but if you are it is usually better to at least recognize the unterminated string as such up to the newline, using a different pattern.

Comment: printf("abc\
def\
ghi");
for this input the correct output will be 
 Token <ID> Lexeme printf found
Token <LPAREN> Lexeme ( found
Token <STRING> Lexeme "abc\
def\
ghi" found
but with your expression it generates
TOKEN <ID> Lexeme printf found
TOKEN <LPAREN> Lexeme ( found
TOKEN <ID> Lexeme abc found
TOKEN <ID> Lexeme def found
TOKEN <ID>Lexeme ghi found

Comment: for unterminated string \"([^"]|\\)* this works fine.

Comment: @sphoenix: if that is what you are getting, there is something wrong with your test harness because the double quotes are vanishing.

Comment: In my assignment file the output is given with quotes.

Comment: I think your original problem was Windows line endings. I edited the answer with a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I forgot I was told about it in my class. You spent a lot time and helped a lot. Thank you.