# Getting strings c-style in flex/lex

Tags: flex-lexer

I want to make a rule in flex to consume c-style strings from the following pattern:
**1)** Letters between " " , for example: "str".
**2)** Can be any of the letter ASCII that can bet printed apart of the following symbols: `\` or `"` or only `\n`.

For example:
"strsr"
"also're\n"

I know that I can to do it with "start conditions" but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is regular expression for multi string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43048602/what-is-regular-expression-for-multi-string)

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 but it's not good: `"\n"`

Comment: @mathques: could you be more specific about the problem? Are you talking about  the pattern in that question or the pattern in the answer?

Comment: OK, here's an answer which includes start conditions for parsing strings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354725/optimizing-flex-string-literal-parsing/42358417. And one more answer with a flex pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43048602/what-is-regular-expression-for-multi-string